# How to summarise number of referrals from different sources by quarter

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I have a DF with two columns (1) = referral source e.g "NHS" which are character strings, and (2) = quarters e.g., 2021 Q1 created with the code

```
referral_df$quarters <-as.yearqtr(referral_df$date,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I want to create a separate DF that sums the number of referrals by source e.g., NHS, private etc. by quarter

so

```
2021Q1 NHS = 400
2021Q1 private = 200
```

or

```
Quarter Source Count
2021Q1 NHS 400
2021Q1 Private 200
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please go through the linked post. If it can't solve your problem, please edit your post to include a reproducible example.